# Como hacer scroll cuando doy click en un botton AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Estoy tratando de hacer que cuando le de `click` en el `botton` maximizar al `div` **numero 2** realice un `scroll` hacia abajo y coloque el div en la parte superior con un `padding-top: 50px;` y así sucesivamente con los otros **elementos**, la idea es que haga `scroll` y ubique estos **elementos** en la parte superior de la pantalla.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.items = [
      {
        "idUnidad": 1,
        "idIdentidad": 1,
        "Nombre": "Quito"
      },
      {
        "idUnidad": 2,
        "idIdentidad": 1,
        "Nombre": "Guayaquil"
      },
      {
        "idUnidad": 3,
        "idIdentidad": 2,
        "Nombre": "Cochabamba"
      },
      {
        "idUnidad": 4,
        "idIdentidad": 2,
        "Nombre": "La paz"
      },
      {
        "idUnidad": 5,
        "idIdentidad": 3,
        "Nombre": "Cusco"
      }
    ];   

    $scope.addAactiveToItem = function(item) {
      item.active = true;
      $scope.activate = true;
    }

    $scope.minItem = function(item) {
      item.active = false;
    }
});
```

```css
.container-div {
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px; 
    height: 150px; 
    margin: 15px;
}
.expanded-div {
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" style="padding: 15px;">
            <div class="container-div" ng-class="{'expanded-div': item.active}">
                <h1>{{ item.idUnidad }}</h1>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addAactiveToItem(item);" ng-if="!item.active">Maximizar este div</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="minItem(item);" ng-if="item.active">Minimizar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Espero que esto se sirva.
He utilizado `scrollIntoView` que te permite ir hacia el elemento seleccionado, de hecho, hago referencia al padre, al div entero, porque si no, te ira hacia el boton. También he añadido mas objetos para hacer las pruebas.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.items = [
      {
        "idUnidad": 3451,
        "idIdentidad": 54,
        "Nombre": "Quito"
      },
{
        "idUnidad": 1567,
        "idIdentidad": 1123,
        "Nombre": "Quito"
      },
{
        "idUnidad": 134,
        "idIdentidad": 1,
        "Nombre": "Quito"
      },
{
        "idUnidad": 21,
        "idIdentidad": 651,
        "Nombre": "Quito"
      },
{
        "idUnidad": 1534,
        "idIdentidad": 3452,
        "Nombre": "Quito"
      },
{
        "idUnidad": 231,
        "idIdentidad": 7654,
        "Nombre": "Quito"
      },
      {
        "idUnidad": 2,
        "idIdentidad": 1,
        "Nombre": "Guayaquil"
      },
      {
        "idUnidad": 3,
        "idIdentidad": 2,
        "Nombre": "Cochabamba"
      },
      {
        "idUnidad": 4,
        "idIdentidad": 2,
        "Nombre": "La paz"
      },
      {
        "idUnidad": 5,
        "idIdentidad": 3,
        "Nombre": "Cusco"
      }
    ];   

    $scope.addAactiveToItem = function(item, $event) {
      item.active = true;
      $scope.activate = true;
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $('#' + $event.target.parentNode.id).offset().top - 20
            }, 500);
    }

    $scope.minItem = function(item) {
      item.active = false;
    }
});
```

```css
.container-div {
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px; 
    height: 150px; 
    margin: 15px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.expanded-div {
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" style="padding: 15px;">
            <div class="container-div" ng-class="{'expanded-div': item.active}" ng-attr-id="{{item.idIdentidad}}">
                <h1>{{ item.idUnidad }}</h1>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addAactiveToItem(item, $event);" ng-if="!item.active">Maximizar este div</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="minItem(item);" ng-if="item.active">Minimizar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muy bien es lo que necesito, pero no se puede hacer que no lo lleve del todo a la parte superior si no que deje un espacio arriba como un **top** o **padding-top** algo asi ?

Comment: Buenas. Hay un metodo, pero este no tiene la animación bonita, aunque se podria reprodcir. En todo caso te dejo como seria con un padding-rop `window.scrollBy(0, $event.clientY - 100)`. simplemente sustituye eso por el `scrollIntoView`

Comment: Modifique mi respuesta antigua, ahora funciona y hace lo que quieres. Revisalo ya que he hecho cambios en los contenedores, ahora llevan una `id` y utilizo el `jQuery`